# Is it possible to see 'accepted' tracked changes in Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, trackchanges

I am working on a scientific paper with other authors, who are commenting and also editing the text.

When I come to review the changes, I can accept or reject their edits. My question is: once I have accepted the edit, is there a way that I can see this again?

I am aware that I can 'see' resolved comments, but cant find a similar feature for edits to the text.

Comment: Hi Cairan, Tom from Overleaf Support here, thanks for asking. Unfortunately no, that's not possible at the moment. Once a tracked change is resolved (by either accepting or rejecting), its information is lost. Sorry for the limitation. Note that we plan to improve the ways how comments and track changes behave, but we're unfortunately not able to give any estimates on this. I hope this helps explain!

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the response. This is far from ideal, hopefully, this will be resolved soon!

Comment: @yo' presumably if you have the pro version with git(hub) sync the user has access to all versions on the git side so could recover this information if some suitable conventions are used in the git commit log to find the relevant changes?

Comment: I use git to check out an overleaf repository, and for me adding or deleting a comment does not lead to changes in the git repo. @yo' you have probably thought about this, but wouldn't it be an idea to store comments in a dotfile or similar in the git repo, so that it would be available to users who really want to dig into the history?